# HorizontalScrollView in NavigationDrawerFragment

Tags: android, user-interface, touch-event

How to divide events which should scroll my ScrollView and events which should manage NavigationDrawer?
Now NavigationDrawer catches all TouchEvent .

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_grey"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/hScrollView"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>



    <View
        android:id="@+id/id10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.company.example.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="288dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

HorizontalScrollView may be not best solution for using within NavigationDrawer, but...

Answer (score 1):

If you ready to give up "swipe to close" feature of the drawer you could lock the drawer when opened. That means user won't be able to close the drawer with a swipe but the scrolling inside `HorizontalScrollView` will work as expected.

The locking is achieved by calling

`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);`

A convenient place for this call would be in `onDrawerOpened`.

Unfortunately the locking also prevents drawer from closing when user taps the scrim (the dimmed part of the screen not occupied by drawer). You'll need to catch that tap and close it yourself, with something like this:

```
mDrawerLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int drawerWidth = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.your_drawer_width);
        if (x > drawerWidth) {
            // inside scrim
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any solution if developer is not ready to give up "swipe to close"? Pozdrav. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
navigationDrawer.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
```

Put the code above after open the navigation drawer and put the following code after close the navigation drawer

```
drawerLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```